# Landing Page SERP = pages of a closed section

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem, please help.

**What I want to see**: pages that have been linked from Google SERP.

**What I configured**:

1. *Source / Medium* = google / organic
2. Report on the parameter "*Landing Page*"

But the report, in the column "Landing Page", includes pages of a **closed section** of users (which can be viewed only after authorization, for example, "/cabinet/..."). Therefore, these pages cannot be pages of the entrance to the site, since they are not available for search robots.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I apologize if I wrote the wrong way. Somehow I went to this resource when looking for feedback from Google Analytics. I will look further

Comment: Hm, my question appeared here - https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/13380274

Comment: Stack overflow is not google support, and its also a programming forum.  Questions about web applications are out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The user could already be authenticated and enter again in your site from SERP or after he has authenticated (staying on your site) 30 minutes of inactivity may have elapsed then he continues browsing (i.e. to /cabinet/) so a new session is created with a landing page inside your system (for how analytics works the source of the new session is inherited from the last one the user had, organic).